# std::bad_alloc issues with smart pointers

Tags: c++, sorting, pointers, smart-pointers, bad-alloc

I am trying to use smart pointers to sort and re-link potentially large data elements for a course assignment. I have defined a class in my code for smart pointers, as listed below:

```
template <typename T>
class sptr {
    public:
        sptr(T *_ptr=NULL) { ptr = _ptr; }
        bool operator<(const sptr &rhs) const {return *ptr < *rhs.ptr;}
        operator T * () const { return ptr; }
    private:
        T *ptr;
};
```

The object I'm trying to sort is a singly-linked list containing class objects with personal records (i.e., names, phone numbers, etc.). The singly-linked list class has an iterator class within it, as listed below.

```
template <class T>
class slist {
  private:
    struct node {
      node() { data=T(); next=NULL; }
      bool operator<(const node & rhs) const {return next < rhs.next;}

      T data;
      node *next;
    };

  node *head;
  node *tail;
  int N;

  public:
    slist();
    ~slist();

    void push_back(const T &);
    void sort();

    class iterator {
       public:
           iterator() : p(NULL) {}
           T & operator*() { return p->data; }
           iterator & operator++() { p = p->next; return *this; }
           bool operator!=(const iterator & rhs) const { return p != rhs.p; }

       private:
           friend class slist<T>;
           iterator(node *p) : p(p) {}
           node *p;
   };

   iterator begin() {return iterator(head->next);}
   iterator end() {return iterator(NULL);}
};
```

The following is my function within my list class for "sorting" using the smart pointers.

```
template <typename T>
void slist<T>::sort(){
    vector< sptr<node> > Ap(N);   // set up smart point array for list
    //slist<T>::iterator iter = begin();
    node *ptrtemp = head->next;
    sptr<node> sptrtemp = ptrtemp;
    for (int i = 0; i < Ap.size() - 1; i++){
        if (Ap[i] != NULL){
            Ap.push_back(sptrtemp);
            ptrtemp = ptrtemp->next;
            sptrtemp = ptrtemp;

            cout << "Temporary Address: " << sptrtemp << "    Vector Element Address: " << Ap[i];
        }
    }

    //sort(Ap.begin(), Ap.end()); // WE GON SORT

    ptrtemp = head;
    for (int j = 0; j < Ap.size() - 1; j++){  // relink using sorted result
        ptrtemp->next = Ap[j];
        sptrtemp = ptrtemp;
        Ap.push_back(sptrtemp);
    }
    ptrtemp->next = NULL;
}
```

tl;dr, I must have a bad smart pointer assignment somewhere because this code compiles, but when I run it, std::bad_alloc happens along with a core dump. Where am I leaking memory? Thanks in advance for your help!

P.S., I've already researched smart pointers further [here](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=25264), and I would just use the standard library's smart pointers if this implementation were not a requirement of the assignment. Also, I know I have my call to std::sort(begin, end) commented out, but I didn't want to start sorting until I got the smart pointers going in the right place.

Comment: Do you *have* to make your own smart pointers? Can't you use e.g. [`std::shared_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) or [`std::unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr)? (Or their Boost counterparts)

Comment: What you have is not really a smart pointer class, as it is not actually managing the memory (at least not in the code you've shown); it is just holding the pointer.  A smart pointer class must properly handle memory management (that is their whole purpose for existence).  Additionally, you are not showing any allocations at all in this code, which will make it impossible for anyone to tell help you diagnose your problem.

Comment: No; our professor wants us to use the "sptr" class for smart pointers he defined in lecture, as in the first post. It further complicates things, but it's something I have to use.

Comment: I figured it didn't do this, Zac. I couldn't tell where it was managing memory either. How, then, would I get this implementation to hold onto memory and link all my elements properly before and after sorting them?

Comment: If I'm not entirely mistaken, you're supposed to store `sptr<node>` throughout the list and not just wrap them when you're sorting.

Comment: @oinkerbob Without knowing the details of your assignment, I can only assume - but I would think molbdnilo is correct and you are supposed to store `sptr<node>` in your list, not `node*` ... and I expect that your professor is wanting you to fully implement the smart pointer class (if not, it is kind of pointless as it isn't doing anything).

Comment: So I shouldn't set my sptr<node> object before stepping through vector of sptr<node>?

Comment: Assuming my pointer assignments within the for loops of slist::sort() are wrong (which I'm certain now that they are), how would I fix them to relink the sorted nodes?